# Use of Timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I am writing a ticket booking system for a movie theater. I want to start a timer that gives users 5 minutes to checkout after they've selected a seat. I decided to use java's Timer class.

Here is the code that starts the timer, and the `expiredCheckout()` function that gets called:

```
private void expiredCheckout() {
        Scanner inputObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Your session has expired!");
            System.out.println("If you want to start over, press 1"); 
            System.out.println("If you want to cancel, press q");
            String input = inputObj.next();
            System.out.println("made it here");
            if (input.equals("q"))
                return;
            else if (input.equals("1")) {
                this.runTheatreUI();
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter valid choice!");
            }
        }
    }

private void startTimer(ArrayList<Seat> seatsSelected) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    expiredCheckout();
                    return;
                }
            }
            ,5*60*1000);
        ArrayList<Object> checkoutInfo = this.checkout();
        timer.cancel();
        if (checkoutInfo.get(0).equals(true)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < seatsSelected.size(); i++) {
                seatsSelected.get(i).setStatus(Seat.TAKEN);
                this.numSeatsAvailable += 1;
            }
        } else {
            // the user quit 
            for (int i = 0; i < seatsSelected.size(); i++) {
                seatsSelected.get(i).setStatus(Seat.OPEN);
                this.numSeatsAvailable += 1;
            }
        }
        return; 
    }
```

As you can see, I added print statements after reading input from the user. However, the function never makes it there. When I enter a character in the terminal, there is no action. I'm confused as to why that happens.

Comment: why do you do `timer.cancel();` ?

Comment: That's not the issue. I understand that the task is asynchronous. But I need to cancel that timer after the checkout function returns, because they have completed the process of booking a seat.

Comment: Yes you have a cancel problem, but as for *However, the function never makes it there. * - I do not think this is true.

Comment: The run() function in the timer class calls expiredCheckout as I want it to. However, it does not get past ```String input = inputObj.nextLine()```. It never prints ```made it here```.

Comment: Hmm, it does on my environment.  Are you sure you haven't shutdown `inputObj` somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

To cancel the timer, you can do this within the TimerTask itself

```
    private void expiredCheckout() {
        System.out.println("in expired method");
        Scanner inputObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Your session has expired!");
            System.out.println("If you want to start over, press 1"); 
            System.out.println("If you want to cancel, press q");
            String input = inputObj.nextLine();
            System.out.println("made it here");
            if (input.equals("q")) {
                System.out.println("quitting");
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
                return;
            }
            else if (input.equals("1")) {
                System.out.println("Entered 1");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please enter valid choice!");
            }
        }                   
    }
```